# Taylor series doesn't seem to have a pattern?

Tags: power-series, taylor-expansion

My teacher gave us a study guide to work on, and one of the problems doesn't seem to come out right. The directions are to "find the Taylor series of $f(x)=x^5-3x^4+x^3+2x-1$ for $a=1$. I calculated the n-th derivatives and wound up with:

$f(1)=0; f'(1)=-2; f''(1)=-10; f'''(1)=-6; f^{(4)}(1)=48; f^{(5)}(1)=120 $

All derivatives afterward are 0.

In order to form the series, I tried plugging these in, but I got this:

$f(x)=(0) + (-2)(x-1) + \frac{(-10)(x-1)^2}{2!} + \frac{(-6)(x-1)^3}{3!} + \frac{48(x-1)^4}{4!} + \frac{120(x-1)^5}{5!}$

So far, I can't find a relationship between the coefficients, even simplifying the factorial. I'm also not sure how I'm supposed to alternate the sign, seeing as it doesn't change predictably. How do I solve this?

Comment: What's wrong with the series that you wrote? Of course you could simplify the fractions, but why do you need some pattern? There are only six coefficients....

Comment: I feel like it's asking me for the concise $\sum x^n etc$ version of the series. I could be wrong. Are they called different things, the written-out series vs the compacted $\sum$ notation?

Comment: polynomials always have a finite taylor series. so there is no sum needed

Comment: Got it. So, should I delete this or do you just want to answer and I can mark it?

Comment: btw first term should be zero

Comment: @MrYouMath noted. thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is nothing wrong with what you have.  The Taylor series of a polynomial, when simplified, is simply itself.  You can try to prove it if you want (for the general polynomial).

Comment: I would add for emphasis that when we express the Taylor series of a polynomial $p(x)$ at a base point $a$ other than $0$, we write $p(x) = b_0 + b_1 (x - a) + \cdots + b_n (x - a)^n$, rather than as a sum $c_0 + c_1 x + \cdots + c_n x^n$.